# Support Kotlin in code highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

The relevant PR was merged into code-prettify: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/491

As per [instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), I'm asking to deploy it to the network and assign to `kotlin` tag.

Comment: [related at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317050/839601)