# Kotlin highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, meta, syntax-highlighting

I motion to reopen [Support Kotlin in code highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299920/support-kotlin-in-code-highlighting) as there's a lot of evidence

It says

> If Kotlin becomes more popular in the future, we will reconsider.

#### Evidence of maturity

There's a [rejected feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299920/support-kotlin-in-code-highlighting) from 2 years back, but since then a lot of things have happened, especially to Kotlin:

- Kotlin is coming up on its 5th major update
- widespread adoption in Android (and some backend)
- Gradle kts build scripts
- official support from Google.

See also the comments on the rejecting answer.

- I think this is a quite compelling evidence that Kotlin is now trending:
  [http://sotagtrends.com/?tags=[kotlin,clojure,groovy,dart,perl,erlang,haskell]&relative=false](http://sotagtrends.com/?tags=%5Bkotlin,clojure,groovy,dart,perl,erlang,haskell%5D&relative=false)
- Kotlin is in quite notable positions in [2019](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology) especially when compared to [2017](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#technology), when it wasn't even on the list.
- 24.8M views according to https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712741/kotlin-total-views

#### Trigger

I just asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224118/how-to-write-strongly-typed-generic-extension-function-in-kotlin) and noticed that even basic highlighting is missing (`fun`/`val` are the most common keywords and they're not highlighted).

Comment: Note that this [tag:feature-request] was marked [tag:declined] when it was asked last time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ohh, that's a 2 year old rejected question, time to re-evaluate?

Comment: Well, maybe explain in your question or at the duplicate what has changed in Kotlin and it's usage  specifically for why this feature-request should be reopened.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did, but I added even more evidence

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do you ask for reopening the other one, because commenting with more and more evidence didn't do much?

Comment: As you've added more support and since the other answer says they're willing to reconsider if usage share is higher, I've issued a vote to reopen. To get others to vote to reopen, I'd recommend [edit]ing in an explicit statement that you're aware of that question and that it does say that they're willing to reconsider.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog thanks, updated; I hope this edit will make a difference, as it was quite quickly hammered to the ground.

Comment: @TWiStErRob that is what gold badges are for. Usually to releave users from suffering comments and downvotes on a question that will close eventually. And make it less work to maintain the site ofcourse.

Comment: Revisiting the language support seems sensible. Considering things have fundamentally changed the old question should be a dupe of the old one, not the other way around.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kotlin highlighting is now live!

Comment: How to enable lang-kotlin highlighting for international SO sites? E.g. on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin/info) there is no code-prettify section in the bottom of the page like on [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin/info).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ follow the instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/51) using the `lang-kotlin` keyword.  And I just turned on auto-highlighting for kotlin associated to that tag on ruSO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yaakov!